# when i sorting parent grid,subgrid is reloading eventhough expandOnload:false and loadOnce:true

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

When i sorting the parent grid,no ajax request is sent for getting data which has to be shown in parent grid. Since i have given "expandOnLoad:true" ajax request is sent for subgrid eventhough i have given "loadonce:true&reloadOnExpand:false"
Is it possible to avoid sending ajax request for getting the data which has to be displayed as subgrid?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you setting the `loadonce : true` , only in the parent grid or for both parent grid and sub-grid.

It should be explicitly set for sub-grid too , for enabling client side sorting

```
$("#price-catalogue-table").jqGrid({
        url : mainGridURL,
        datatype : "json",
        .................
        .................
        .................
        loadonce : true,
        subGrid: true,
        subGridOptions: {
                          reloadOnExpand : false,
                          selectOnExpand : true,
                          expandOnLoad:true
                          },
        subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
                ............
                ............
                 $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
                         url:subGridURL,
                         datatype: "json",
                         loadonce : true,
```

So make sure it is used in both the grid definition. And if the issue still persist then use this on `loadcomplete` of subgrid if you are using `datatype: "json"` ,

```
 $("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'local'});
```

Comment: I had given loadonce:true in both parent and sub grid. I also tried loadComplete function as you suggested..but still ajax request is made for getting data in subgrid

Comment: So what data type are you using then for subgrid , is it local or something else ?

Comment: From ajax return data type is json. In loadComplete i have set the datatype to local